# How do you create an array of temporary files in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I need to have multiple temporary files. I decided that an array is best for that because I indeed to create 10 temporary files, use them and them remove the 10 files. From researching I've come up with this:

```sh
declare -A my_array
my_array=()

for i in `seq -w 1 10`
do
    my_array[$i]= $(mktemp /tmp/$i.XXXX)

done

#Do stuff with the files in the array

for i in `seq -w 1 10`
do
    rm my_array[$i]
done
```

However, this gives me the error:

```
./plot.sh: line 7: /tmp/01.PkUG: Permission denied 
./plot.sh: line 7: /tmp/02.eFNZ: Permission denied And so on...
```

I'm confused because when I create the 10 files without the loop it works fine, but is obviously very messy:

```sh
tmpfile1=$(mktemp /tmp/data1.XXX)
tmpfile2=$(mktemp /tmp/data2.XXX)
And so on...

#And then remove

rm $tmpfile1
rm $tmpfile2
And so on....
```

Comment: Better to create a temp directory and just name your files 1, 2, 3,...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of syntax errors which I've marked below:

```
declare -A my_array
my_array=()

for i in `seq -w 1 10`
do
    my_array[$i]=$(mktemp /tmp/$i.XXXX)
    #           ^^
    #           | no space
done

#Do stuff with the files in the array

for i in `seq -w 1 10`
do
    rm "${my_array[$i]}"
    #  ^^^            ^^
    #   |              | dollar sign and curly braces required, quotes recommended
done
```

Try using [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check your scripts for errors. It has better diagnostics than the shell's built-in ones. It can be downloaded as a CLI tool, or you can just paste your script into the web site. Pretty convenient!

Some additional improvements:

- There's no need to use `declare -A` when you've got a regular non-associative array.
- `for ((i = 0; i < n; i++))` avoids an unnecessary call to an external process like `seq`.
- You can append to an array with `array+=(items...)`.
- You can often avoid explicitly looping over arrays. Many commands, `rm` included, take lists of file names, which you can use to your advantage. `"${array[@]}"` expands to all of the items in the array.
- There's no real need to micromanage `mktemp`'s file name generation. Letting it use the default algorithm is nice because it'll respect the user's `$TMPDIR` setting in case they want to use a directory other than `/tmp`. (If you do want to control the file name use `--tmpdir` to get the same behavior.)

```
files=()
for ((i = 1; i <= 10; i++)); do
    files+=("$(mktemp)")     # or: files+=("$(mktemp --tmpdir "$i".XXXX)")
done

# Do stuff with files in the array.
rm "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: Maybe the `declare -A` was meant as a workaround for `seq -w` which will output 08 and be invalid as an integer expression.

Comment: Alternate option with `mapfile`: `mapfile -t -d '' tempfiles < <(for ((i = 0; i < 10; i++)); do printf '%s\0' "$(mktemp -u $'tmp.XXXXXXXXXX')"; done)`. Too bad `mktemp` has no option to generate multiple temporary files in one go, and output with custom delimiter.